# Campo adicional numa tabela Base de dados para a remoção

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia

Criei uma base de dados, em que estou com alguns problemas quando procedo a remoção de algum dado da tabela.

Exemplo Stand de vendas:
Tenho um vendedor que foi despedido e quero remover-lo da bd mas não posso porque esse vendedor tem associado a ele 1000 e tal vendas... 
E não posso apagar as 1000 e tal vendas por causa do vendedor...

Eu sei que para resolver esse problema, uma das soluções é adicionar um campo a cada tabela em que quando esse dado é removido esse campo passa a false ou 0 e quando está ativo esse campo está a true ou 1.

**Pergunta**

Como se chama essa maneira de resolver? isto é se existir um nome para ela

Exemplo: se eu disser que vou usar "*Singleton*" numa classe automaticamente quem conhecer essa *Design Pattern* sabe o que vou fazer.

Existe algum nome desse género para essa maneira de resolver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em inglês, dizemos simplesmente *"mark as deleted"* (tipo, "marcar como removido"), e de fato é uma prática comum. Não conheço nenhuma terminologia alternativa para essa prática, mas posso estar enganado. (uma busca rápida no Google me trouxe o termo *"soft delete"*, mas essa foi a primeira vez que vi o mesmo)

A propósito, existem outras alternativas para o que você pretende fazer, não necessariamente melhores mas ainda são opções:

- Criar um vendedor "especial" cuja função é se tornar dono de toda venda que ficar "órfã" (mais ou menos como o nosso usuário [Comunidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade)). Possível, embora você perca algumas estatísticas interessantes se fizer dessa forma.
- Separar aquilo que é permanente daquilo que é transitório: às vezes pode ser interessante manter um histórico do que aconteceu na empresa, quem passou por ela, quem fez o que, etc, mas ao mesmo tempo é necessário (por lei, por exemplo) que os dados pessoais de um ex-funcionário ou ex-cliente sejam permanentemente removidos após certo tempo. A solução então é ter uma tabela separada para "o vendedor" (apenas com campos "genéricos", como um UUID) e outra para "os dados pessoals do vendedor" (nome, sobrenome, endereço, telefone de contato, lista de documentos, etc) com chave estrangeira para a primeira tabela.

  A primeira tabela nunca tem dados removidos nem mesmo marcados como removidos. A segunda é onde você busca por vendedores ativos (i.e. se você precisa de um vendedor, procure na tabela de dados pessoais, não na tabela mestre), e uma vez que um deles sai da empresa você pode simplesmente apagar seus dados e o resto continua como está. Nos relatórios futuros, vai constar que "o vendedor f47ac10b-58cc-4372-a567-0e02b2c3d479 fez uma venda no valor de X na data Y", etc.

Comment: Obrigado... Como você disse e bem "não necessariamente melhores mas ainda são opções" para o exemplo que dei, a primeira seria uma solução muito má porque a venda ficaria sem o responsável, alguém que no caso de ter corrido alguma coisa mal "por as culpas" **Mas** na segunda opção falou num assunto que nunca tinha pensado(acho eu) relativamente as base de dados, a integridade  dos dados, muito obrigado mais uma vez...

Answer (score 0):

Crie um campo DATA_DA_DEMISSAO, sinaliza a saída do mesmo e mantém o histórico.